# Ubuntu and Windows 7: can't choose boot option. Always Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot

I've a Windows 7 working for a while. I tried to install Ubuntu 10.10. I did a shirnk on the Windows 7 partition so I could install Ubuntu. Started installation, chose automatic partition. It went through installation smoothly, but whenever a start de computer it always goes to Windows 7, the boot loader never shows up with options on what OS I want to go.

Basically, Ubuntu is installed alongside a Windows 7, but I can access it.

Windows 7 was not harmed on the operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the boot loader of Windows 7 with [BCDEdit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[Boot Configuration Data Editor Frequently Asked Questions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721886%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[BCDEdit Command-Line Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28WS.10%29.aspx)